# How to get distinct employees that do not have a particular skillset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table that has two columns. Employee_id (which is unique per employee) and next column for employee skillset. One employee can have multiple skillset. How do I retrieve the list of distinct employees who don't have skillset 'c' if A,B,C,D,E are the five types of skillset that employees can have.

```
employee_id skillset
1           A
1           C
2           E
3           A
3           B
3           C
4           D
4           C
5           B
```

I have tried self join and other methods but it is not working.

```
select distinct employee_id from employee_skillset where skillset not like 'C'
```

When I run my query, it is still giving me employee_ids that have skillset of "c"

Comment: Well, have you considered WHY you get those answers? Basically your query first selects all rows where skillset is not C. Then you ask for the distinct ID's. Sounds as if you need some attack from the other end.

Comment: Use sub-query with `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by employee_id` and set a condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select employee_id 
from employee_skillset 
group by employee_id
having sum(case when skillset = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct s.employee_id 
from employee_skillset s
where not exists (
  select 1 from employee_skillset
  where employee_id = s.employee_id and skillset = 'C'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your expected results from your data set? 2 and 5?

Why not something like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id
FROM Table1
WHERE skillset <> 'C';
```

Comment: *Why not something like below* because this will return employees with skill 'C' if they also have another skill.

Answer (score 0):

`MINUS` set operator is one option:

```
SQL> with employee_skillset (employee_id, skillset) as
  2    (select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'c' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'e' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'a' from dual union all
  6     select 3, 'b' from dual union all
  7     select 3, 'c' from dual union all
  8     select 4, 'd' from dual union all
  9     select 4, 'c' from dual union all
 10     select 5, 'b' from dual
 11    )
 12  select employee_id from employee_skillset
 13  minus
 14  select employee_id from employee_skillset where skillset = 'c';

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
          2
          5

SQL>
```

---

Yet another option:

```
 <snip>
 12  select employee_id
 13  from (select employee_id,
 14               case when skillset = 'c' then 1 else 0 end flag
 15        from employee_skillset
 16       )
 17  group by employee_id
 18  having sum(flag) = 0;

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
          2
          5

SQL>
```

---

Or:

```
 <snip>
 12  select employee_id
 13  from (select employee_id,
 14               listagg(skillset, ',') within group (order by null) lagg
 15        from employee_skillset
 16        group by employee_id
 17       )
 18  where instr(lagg, 'c') = 0;

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
          2
          5

SQL>
```